# What is the best way to send password from app server to authentication micro service?

Tags: node.js, microservices

I am currently in a process to develop micro service architecture in one of my projects. I have one public layer of App Servers which actually routes the user requests to relevant micro services and replies back to client. My mirco services are in private layer.

Currently i am using REST API to send data back and forth. However, I was wondering, what is the best way to send username and password from app server to micro service? Should I use plain text format as micro service is in private layer? Please suggest best way.

Comment: how about implementing an OAuth2 server and validating using its token?

Comment: @alternatiph, I was thinking, even if we go and implement OAuth2 server, we still need to send passwords from app server to OAuth2 server to generate tokens. Then again, same question arises, how to send password from app to OAuth2 server?

Comment: As far as i know, the user authenticate itself via sending her username/password to `auth` server and receives a token. After that for any other request, she sends the token to `resource server`. The `resource server` validate the token by communicating to `auth server` and receives confimation. Therefore no username and/or password is being sent during this process after login.

Comment: and for your last question, try sending password over https, hashing it with a salt or common key between client and server (in particular something that can be decrypted on server)

Comment: @alternatiph, but my auth server is in a private layer. Are you suggesting to have auth server in public layer?

Comment: not necessarily. you can create an abstract layer to handle your login/register requests. Either way using HTTPS and/or encrypting & decrypting the password pretty much secures your communication.

Comment: take a look at this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55693/securing-passwords-for-rest-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I think using SSL connection to your microservice and pain text password in body of HTTP request is the general way of doing logins in client applications.